# I want to generate the class source from wsdl but I got an error caused by the certificate installed on the server is invalid

Tags: java, ssl, soap, wsdl

[image]the application is to consume a soap web service but the certificate installed on the server refuses the connection here is my error message

```
Exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import remote website certificate into your local java cert store using this [tutorial](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/)

Comment: thank you I did everything in the tutorial but it still displays the same error

Comment: [ERROR] Could not retrieve the last modification timestamp for the URI [https://xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/createCustomer?wsdl] from the HTTP URL connection. The [Last-Modified] header was probably not set correctly.
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [].

Comment: Exception : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Comment: is your "xxx.xxx..." a kind of localhost/handmade? Do you receive any error when opening wsdl in a browser? Perhaps, the certificate is not good...

Comment: good on the browser it works but if I try to recover the wsdl on spring boot java it generates an error

Comment: the certificate on the server is self signed

Comment: hmm, it's weird. Most likely you have not imported certificate well. Try to delete the existing one from the store using 'keytool delete'. And/or import once again with '-alias <your_alias>'. Verify that the certificate is good and valid 'keytool -v'. The other option is that you have several JVM installations and run wsimport (using maven plugin) from a different java home.